# Use material-ui table with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: material-ui

I'm looking to use material-ui in combination with react-beautiful-dnd in order to make a sortable table. However, using material-ui's table components causes trouble as TableBody won't accept innerRef and TableRow won't accept innerRef and isDragging. See my code below:

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
  <Fragment>
    <Table className={classes.table}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          <TableCell numeric>Number</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Time</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <Droppable droppableId="table">
        {(droppableProvided) => (
          <TableBody
            innerRef={(ref) => {
              this.tableRef = ref;
              droppableProvided.innerRef(ref);
            }}
            {...droppableProvided.droppableProps}
          >
            {this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
              <Draggable
                draggableId={user.id}
                index={index}
                key={user.id}
              >
                {(
                  provided,
                  snapshot,
                ) => (
                  <TableRow
                    innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                  >
                    <TableCell><DragIndicatorIcon /></TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell numeric>{user.number}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>10</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                )}
              </Draggable>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </Table>
  </Fragment>
</DragDropContext>
```

How can I get material-ui to be usable with these attributes?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Can you share the code?

Comment: We eventually moved on to a different library (react-drag-listview) where this problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @Yannick : any inputs you can provide for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738982/material-ui-drag-and-drop-table-row-to-other-table. I want to do same thing but between two tables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem. What you have to do is move the Draggable/Droppable part into a component and pass that in via the component attribute.

For example, I wanted to be able to re-order columns in a table header. Row is my droppable area, and Cell is Draggable.

```
public render() {
    return (
        <TableHead component="div">
            <TableRow component={DroppableComponent(this.onDragEnd)}>{headerCells}</TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}

const DroppableComponent = (
    onDragEnd: (result: DropResult, provided: ResponderProvided) => void
) => (props: any) => {
    return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId={'1'} direction="horizontal">
                {(provided) => {
                    return (
                        <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} {...props}>
                            {props.children}
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
    );
};
```

Notice I made Droppable Component be a function that returns a function. That was so that I could pass in the onDragEnd method from my main component. I tried putting my DroppableComponent in the component attribute as JSX and I was getting an error, so this is what I ended up with.

For the Draggable part I had the following:

```
<TableCell
    component={DraggableComponent(column.id, index)}
    key={column.id}
>
    ...
</TableCell>

const DraggableComponent = (id: string, index: number) => (props: any) => {
    return (
        <Draggable draggableId={id} index={index}>
            {(provided) => (
                <div
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    {...props}
                >
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    );
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have a github repo where I can see this?

Comment: @Bryant : can we do same between two tables ?
i.e. dragging from left table and dropping the row in right table ?

Comment: @ShreyaBhatnagar looks like react-beautiful-dnd supports dragging between two containers/tables like you are asking. I haven't attempted to use the solution I have above in that context though, but in principle it should work. I also don't use this library actively anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this while working on a similar task. Re the OP's question, `TableRow` and `TableBody` both support a `ref` prop (vs. `innerRef`) that forwards to the root element.

Refer to the FAQ:

- https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-access-the-dom-element

This is mentioned in the docs for both `TableRow` and `TableBody`:

- https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/
- https://material-ui.com/api/table-body/

Therefore you do not necessarily need to move the Draggable/Droppable parts into their own components per the answers from @Bryant and @funql.org.

You also don't necessarily need to pass `isDragging` to your `TableRow` (though you could if you created a custom wrapper component that accepts this prop). If your use-case is styling the row when dragged, you can add a `className` or `style` prop to your `TableRow` and apply conditional styling when `isDragging` is `true`.

Here's a working example of a Material UI table that features sortable rows with react-beautiful-dnd:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-and-react-beautiful-dnd-uofv4

Incidentally I created it as part of an [issue report](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1887) because I'm not sure why there is a 1 pixel jump (the thickness of the border-bottom on table cells) when a given table row is dragged, but that's another issue! The implementation is solid enough to support the many cases where a minor 1px visual glitch is acceptable.

Comment: Your working example has some flaw that is also happening with me. When dragging the row, it "shrinks" its width, causing the entire contents to be difficult to read. I'm still struggling to find a fix for this.

Comment: It seems that a lot of element-specific styling is automatically injected, causing the draggable object to shrink. As element-specific styling overrides any class styling (unless you manage ugly !important properties to get through), then providing some class when isDragging is true won't solve this.

Comment: Hi @RuiMiguelPinheiro I didn't bother implementing this detail because I originally created that codesandbox for a bug report. However, if you look at the code in `MaterialTable.tsx` I actually made a comment about this shrinking behaviour and suggested a resolution :). I have a project where I implement a `DraggableTableCell` that uses a `useMeasure()` hook that uses the ResizeObserver API. It "locks" the cell's width + height with an inline style when an `isDragging` prop is true, using the 'cached' width + height obtained from the hook. This solves the issue.

Comment: For anyone needing this, the solution @firxworx outlined for the width shrinkage has a close enough implementation here: https://github.com/pschlan/cron-job.org/blob/eb7b325e2f8eef630fced7c10166bd95f90a9feb/frontend/src/components/misc/Table.jsx#L42
Oddly it worked after I changed if (isDragging) --> if (!isDragging)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a github example repo using @Bryant's solution.
https://github.com/hmarggraff/react-material-ui-table-row-drag-and-drop

It shows how to combine Bryants solution with react-material-ui. It also shows row vs colums dnd and visual feedback during dnd. It is a complete reusable solution.

Comment: What is the added benefit or insight this answer provides compared to the one by Bryant? I mean apart from the benefit for you that it might attract users to your github though the knowhow is not by you. If you provide more, then please explain it here. Otherwise please consider whether this post might give an unfavorable impression of your intentions. Some more explanation would probably put it into a better light. Also, this might be mistaken for a link-only answer, which as such might get deleted.

Comment: It answers the request by Kimaya. And it provides a complete solution for re-use. Not just code fragments. It shows how to combine Bryants solution with react-material-ui. It also shows row vs colums dnd and visual feedback during dnd. What is the benefit of your comment, except increasing comment count?

Comment: See, that is additional benefit. Now however it is a link-only answer, because it only states what the link provides but not how that is done. You can change that, by describing the core methods for achieving the additional benefit, directly here in the answer. (The downvote is not by me by the way.)

Comment: By the way, I can see that somebody asked for a github. But what people hope to find on StackOverflow and what StackOverflow is meant to provide or designed to allow are different things.

Comment: @funql.org  can we do same between two tables ? i.e. dragging from left table and dropping the row in right table ?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers mostly will work for react versions < 18.0 . For latest versions checkout this sandbox. Here is how I managed to add drag and dropdown functionality with material UI table:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-with-drag-and-drop-rows-515mwz?file=/demo.js

Comment: This uses a fork called `@hello-pangea/dnd`. Subbing that with `react-beautiful-dnd@13`  breaks it, so there must be a fix in the fork.