# React beautiful dnd not working with React Semantic UI Table

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I've tried to use react-beautiful-dnd in combination with React Semantic UI Table, but I cannot get it to work properly because of provided.innerRef issues ( https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/using-inner-ref.md). 
I've seen some users experience similar issues with material ui too. ([Use material-ui table with react-beautiful-dnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839298/use-material-ui-table-with-react-beautiful-dnd)).
Here is the code sample which is working properly for a normal html table but not for a semantic ui react table: https://codesandbox.io/s/l467j0wj7m.
I will appreciate any feedback, solutions or workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/84vz99mxn9).

Put a `Ref` around `Table.Body` and set the `provided.innerRef` on `Ref` rather than on `Table.Body`:

```
{(provided, snapshot) => (
    <Ref innerRef={provided.innerRef}>
        <Table.Body {...provided.droppableProps}>
        </Table.Body>
    </Ref>
)}
```

And the same for `Table.Row`:

```
{(provided, snapshot) => (
    <Ref innerRef={provided.innerRef}>
        <Table.Row  {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
        </Table.Row>
    </Ref>
)}
```

That should do the trick. See also: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/859